# Lambda container image: AccessDeniedException: User is not authorized to perform dynamodb BatchWriteItem on resource: table?

Tags: lambda, containers, boto3

I am running a container saved on ECR with a lambda function.
The container uses boto3 to interact with s3 and dynamodb, works well when running on local because I am calling it with AWS CLI configure credentials.
I tried assigning roles for full access to the lambda function, but it does not work.

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the BatchWriteItem operation: 
User: arn:aws:sts::******:assumed-role/*********-role-******/app_******* is not authorized to perform: 
dynamodb:BatchWriteItem on resource
```

Is there a proper way to authorize and run a container that uses boto3?

Comment: "I tried assigning roles" what roles? Your question lacks details and is unclear. Can you provide full definition of these "roles"?

Comment: Can you show the IAM policy you applied to the role to grant it access to the dynamo table?

Answer (score -1):

I solved by adding AWS credentials as environment variables in the Dockerfile:

```
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=***
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=***
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=***
```

Comment: if you are running Lambda, normally you should attach or edit the policy of the IAM role, you added to the Lambda function itself, to grant access to your resources. Providing AWS credentials within AWS to access resources (also available within AWS) is not recommended (e.g. if your credentials have FullAccess, you provide also FullAccess to everything to your docker and you should think about it, if you want to to this). So... find out your IAM role of your Lambda and check your policies.